# Can I refer to an XSD type by its ID?

Tags: xml, xsd

Seemingly every tag in XSD has an optional ID attribute that can be specified, but what is the point? I would like to refer to a type by using it, but I'm unsure if that's possible.

Example: Normally someone would use the name

```
<xsd:simpleType name="myType" id="1">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="myDerivedType>
  <xsd:simpleType ref="myType"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Instead, I would want to use this:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="myType" id="1">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="myDerivedType>
  <xsd:simpleType refById="1"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And for it to still have the same effect. Essentially, I want one of two ways to reference a simple type. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The purpose if the `id` attribute

The `id` attribute facilitates the use of short-form or short-hand XPointer as fragment identifiers in URIs:

[XML Schema Part 1: Structures > 3.15.2.2 References to Schema Components from Elsewhere](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#d0e16826)

> The names of schema components such as type definitions and element declarations are not of type ID: they are not unique within a schema, just within a symbol space. This means that simple fragment identifiers will not always work to reference schema components from outside the context of schema documents.
>
> [...]
>
> Short-form fragment identifiers may also be used in some cases, that is when a DTD or XML Schema is available for the schema in question, and the provision of an `id` attribute for the representations of all primary and secondary schema components, which *is* of type ID, has been exploited.

A fragment identifier is part of a uri (e.g. `https://www.example.com/#fragment-identifier`) - how this is processed depends on the media type:

[RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax > 3.5. Fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5)

> The fragment's format and resolution is therefore
> dependent on the media type [RFC2046] of a potentially retrieved
> representation, even though such a retrieval is only performed if the
> URI is dereferenced.

For XML, fragment identifiers are XPointers:

[RFC 7303: XML Media Types > 5. Fragment Identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7303#section-5)

> The syntax and semantics of fragment identifiers for the XML media
> types defined in this specification are based on the
> [XPointerFramework] W3C Recommendation.

And the XPointer framework specifies shorthand pointers as follow:

[XPointer Framework > 3.2 Shorthand Pointer](https://www.w3.org/TR/xptr-framework/#shorthand)

> A shorthand pointer, formerly known as a barename, consists of an NCName alone. It identifies at most one element in the resource's information set; specifically, the first one (if any) in document order that has a matching NCName as an identifier. The identifiers of an element are determined as follows:
>
> 1. If an element information item has an attribute information item among its **[attributes]** that is a schema-determined ID, then it is identified by the value of that attribute information item's [schema normalized value] property;

It should be noted that the XSD ID type (`xs:ID`), and `id` attributes which has this type are not numeric and the value you used in your example (`1`) would not be valid for `id` attribute:

[XML Schema Part 1: Structures > 3.14.2 (non-normative) XML Representation of Simple Type Definition Schema Components](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-datatype)

> ```
> <simpleType
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>   id = ID
> ```

(Schema Part 2: Datatypes > 3.3.8 ID)[https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#ID]

> [Definition:]   **ID** represents the ID attribute type from [XML 1.0 (Second Edition)]. The ·value space· of **ID** is the set of all strings that ·match· the NCName production in [Namespaces in XML]. The ·lexical space· of ID is the set of all strings that ·match· the NCName production in [Namespaces in XML]. The ·base type· of **ID** is NCName.

[Namespaces in XML > 2. Declaring Namespaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#NT-NCName)

> ```
> [4]   NCName  ::= (Letter | '_') (NCNameChar)*    /*  An XML Name, minus the ":" */
> [5]   NCNameChar  ::= Letter | Digit | '.' | '-' | '_' | CombiningChar | Extender
> ```

### Referencing other schema components by `id`

It is not possible to refer to other XSD components (which includes XSD types) by `id` within XSD itself. The only semantics specified in XSD for referencing other schema components is via QName. For example:

[XML Schema Part 1: Structures > 3.3.2 XML Representation of Element Declaration Schema Components](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-element)

> ```
> <element
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>   ref = QName
>   substitutionGroup = QName
>   type = QName
> ```

QName is defined as follow in XML Schema:

[XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes > 3.2.18 QName](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#QName)

> [Definition:] QName represents XML qualified names. The ·value space· of QName is the set of tuples {namespace name, local part}, where namespace name is an anyURI and local part is an NCName. The ·lexical space· of QName is the set of strings that ·match· the QName production of [Namespaces in XML].

> **Note**:  The mapping between literals in the ·lexical space· and values in the ·value space· of QName requires a namespace declaration to be in scope for the context in which QName is used.

[Namespaces in XML 1.0 > 4 Qualified Names](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-qualnames)

> ```
> [7]     QName             ::= PrefixedName
>                               | UnprefixedName
> [8]     PrefixedName      ::= Prefix ':' LocalPart
> [9]     UnprefixedName    ::= LocalPart
> ```

The process of resolving a QName to a schema component is defined as:

[XML Schema Part 1: Structures > 3.15.3 Constraints on XML Representations of Schemas](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#src-resolve)

> #### Schema Representation Constraint: QName resolution (Schema Document)
>
> For a ·QName· to resolve to a schema component of a specified kind all of the following must be true:

> [...]

> 2 The component's {name} matches the ·local name· of the ·QName·;

> [...]

And *{name}* refers to the `name` attribute of components:

[XML Schema Part 1:  > 3.2.2 XML Representation of Attribute Declaration Schema Components](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-attribute)

> {name}  The ·actual value· of the `name` [attribute]

[XML Schema Part 1:  > 3.3.2 XML Representation of Element Declaration Schema Components](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-element)

> {name}  The ·actual value· of the `name` [attribute]

[XML Schema Part 1:  > 3.4.2 XML Representation of Complex Type Definitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-type)

> {name} The ·actual value· of the `name` [attribute] if present, otherwise ·absent·.

To conclude, the only semantics in XSD for referring to other schema components is by using their names.